# location of injury occurence and are these injuries logical?

Tags: injury

It is essential to the plot of my story for My character (human) to be injured. I know her injuries which are, her leg and right arm bones are either fractured or broken in different places. Her right shoulder is dislocated. On her left arm, her fingers and hand are broken as well as her wrist and her elbow is dislocated. 3 ribs broke on her right side and there is one rib dislocation. Other than huge scrapes and a concussion and gash on the head. Her right side is the most beat up but her left still has significant injuries. These injuries are impact injuries. What I am having trouble is what caused it? It has to look almost suicidal.

So maybe hit by a train? At what speed, is my character in a vehicle? Did the force of the train push her out?

Did my character fall somewhere in the Grand Canyon ( they are in Arizona) Did my character just fall into the river or on the stone? was there anything blocking her fall, like foliage?

Did she fall from a building onto cement? was there a tree blocking her path? Did she hit a balcony or something first? At what height?

From a bridge in Arizona? At what height? did she hit something underwater? Was she pulled downstream?

What is the most logical way to obtain her injuries? What other ways could she have been injured?

Comment: Just so you're aware... A fracture and a break are the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

Examples of accidents in which the described injuries can occur:

- Falling from the height (>4 m) on the hard surface, especially when trying to ease the impact with the hands (Here's one military report of [parachuting accidents](https://watermark.silverchair.com/49-1-17.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAApYwggKSBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggKDMIICfwIBADCCAngGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMcxTUvxUC8haftPItAgEQgIICSUGSHiIZOYHURR10rXFPubpCxJmWwdjkxIpZa6jR7aaFiJeC4rEAlLF254bzDxiu2ygfY67BwB-vXPXyFiAx4hgm3kf2oFEvjvstHttEWb-oAcdlyt-KXnHxZtNbY8IZ1MR9u_nMrd1Ts0wwMakbrLQNNemJJXF6XMTUZN6B97LbjWQdU3SMRKBduK5fPgpkGFExXPWK9ehm7CQSGlAIq1m-sRwSseLB-PcWSI46PQxpyD793-qdYEgYcdrr30J_h5YAflt5bj0q_IoLHmRck8DKlIjFL2j2badC8Gnke3KfQzOG8FJq-yKhZs_wM4LX6amIaUEdNL9oPNtQElu3U6BJbPDQCPtoi1pBruRYK-Q4ABd1tOIAcKp7_dTM96DIiWVu-JZCWt0tveyEk9zPyqkex0NY19SDfmQmoCiAWMM8kq5NiHullEkzIGRHs02DG9-OZF9ZqRdBpYRm0aPNrn_WaI_17Nofaf_lST9Lzxyb1xmBNUJaF2ilc-Mr-mnC569H6AbtO4kV073nO1HM1rhixeujzTZ1kOr9grA3o7h7kowWRknzidFYRgs1V5s7oWx51HIkO-PzB6kr1IyTBQQXKtldF-bGlOYSQ2HG8jSCFzvsSWDX7BbaD6QZHBvIaRjaEdl6Vmp6nuKGVsffWTzOcEYqLQ3elKf4L_PvREOzcKVw11yzBeREIivU-rGKG6gMT3v5U0tNBWajas_e-LGjsLq3AK_oQI-FjznAtWWXcDO4IVBn1hGefGgVr1IR2wo0kCwLGqmTZA) with detailed list of injuries in Table 4)
- Falling down a steep slope, such as in the mountains, and hitting rocks on the way down and at the bottom
- The car slipping from the road and rolling down the hill; the person does not use a security belt
- [A pedestrian being hit by a car](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3256841/) (detailed injury description)
- Driving a car without using a security belt and without having an air bag and being involved in a head-on collision with another car
- Getting hit by the train when crossing the railway by a car
- Falling in the river (from the boat, banks or bridge) and then being rolled over the rocks in the rapids

Falling from the bridge into a deep water as such may not necessary cause all those exact injuries, especially not in the hands and fingers.

Comment: I don't think your first and last suggestions are plausible. The first one would be unlikely to cause fractured ribs and concussion. As for the last one, surviving being hit by a train is very unlikely. That's virtually always instantly fatal. And, of course, you need some supporting references.

Comment: Naaah, there are videos in which the train hits the car and pushes it away - the person can be severely injured but can survive. The first reason is common - people fall from height when jumping from windows to escape from fire or fall in parashut accidents - the news are full of these and with detailed injuries described.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the word "car" in your answer. I thought you were suggesting a pedestrian hit by a train. As for falling, sure, that's possible, but the way you wrote it ("landing on the hands") suggests a single point of impact. There are going to have to be multiple impacts to inflict all the injuries described.